# Instruct brew doctor to ignore specific *.dylib files

Tags: homebrew, dylib

How can I instruct `brew doctor` to ignore specific `*.dylib` files?

e.g., `brew doctor` outputs:

```
Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib
```

`/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib` is file that should never conflict with anything from `brew`.

Is there a config file and/or a command-line switch with which I can instruct `brew doctor` to ignore `/usr/local/lib/libecomlodr.dylib`?

Answer (score 2):

No you can’t. `brew doctor` helps diagnose problems but not everything it mentions are real issues. As maintainers, we ask people to post its output when they have an issue to quickly see if there’s something that could be the cause, but feel free to ignore what it says if you think it’s normal.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to skip certain brew doctor checks, in this case not looking for stray files:

```
brew doctor $(brew doctor --list-checks | grep -v stray)
```