# Can I tell brew doctor to ignore some files

Tags: homebrew

`brew doctor` is telling me about some header and library files in `/usr/local/lib` that I want to keep and are perfectly expected - is there a way I can tell `brew doctor` to not warn me about these?

Comment: `brew doctor 2>&1 | grep -v "stuff I know about"` maybe? So if you know about `packageXYZ` try `brew doctor 2>&1 | grep -v "XYZ"`

Comment: That will work - but I was suggesting a `brew` config file of some sort to handle that.

Comment: I think Baptiste's answers on **homebrew** are normally rock solid... https://stackoverflow.com/a/31510976/2836621

Comment: OK - I'll wrap brew in my own util with code like the one you suggest above. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSetchell would you mind writing this in an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @bfontaine I have added an answer - please feel free to edit/improve it if necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a way of *"white-listing"* for `brew doctor` things that you are already aware of and happy to accept. I can only suggest you use an inverse `grep` to filter them out, e.g.:

```
brew doctor 2>&1 | grep -v "stuff I know about"
```

So, if you know about `packageXYZ`, try:

```
brew doctor 2>&1 | grep -v "packageXYZ"
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31510976/2836621) answer.